# Mirror dual monitors with different resolutions

Tags: xrandr

I use the following `xrandr` command to mirror my 17" laptop with a 27" external 
 monitor, so I can use it to do presentations:

`xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as LVDS1`

However, the external monitor (HDMI1) falls back to a 1600x900 resolution instead of 1920x1080.

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis
   1600x900       60.0 +
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't mind panning on laptop try this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080* --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as LVDS1
```

Comment: Super great, had no idea this was supported!

Comment: Seems to be a bug actually getting _out_ of this mode-- `xrandr --output $external --primary` followed by `xrandr --output $internal --primary` solved this for me (suggested [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1326688))

Comment: Why is there '*' in the argument for `--panning` there? The manual does not say anything about it.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is how I modified the resolutions to work with my UltraWide (21:9) monitor: `xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 2560x1080 --panning 2560x1080--output HDMI2 --mode 2560x1080 --same-as eDP1`. This causes some glitches when panning the laptop display, but I don't use it much so it is fine with me.

Comment: After disconnecting the external display, I do`xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080` toget back to normal on my laptop. You can add `xrandr --HDMI2 --off` before thatif you want to avoid the xrandr warning message.

Comment: I should also not that I do experience some lag on the external display when the mouse pointer traverses the area where the laptop screen starts panning.

Answer (score 9):

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080 --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --scale-from 1920x1080 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --same-as LVDS1
```

or you could do it another way around to use the resolution of LVDS1 as base resolution, but then you have lower quality on HDMI1.

Comment: Note: to list your displays use `xrandr --listactivemonitors`

Comment: @VasyaNovikov There is also `--listmonitors`. There is nothing about them in manual page of `xrandr`.

Comment: I just checked, xrandr version 1.5.1 (ArchLinux) has information about it in the man page, in `--help` and in auto-completion (tested on bash).

Comment: @VasyaNovikov oh, but it is not in the (Ubuntu) man page of 1.5.0 and older.

Comment: yeah, I thought so. Personally, I got tired of living in 6-24 months outdated software, so always having the latest stable versions from a rolling distro feels like a very nice thing. I'd wish Ubuntu would make a "rolling release" flavor of its OS. Let's see. This is also off-topic of course.

Comment: BTW, I hope I don't sound like an aggressive <distro_name> fan, but I've discovered this possibility just a few minutes ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/678113/64255  You can apparently turn your Ubuntu into a rolling release. Again, sorry for the off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `xrandr` is not very good at handling dual monitors in `--same-as` configuration,  when the monitors do not have the same resolution. Appart from falling back to highest common resolution of both monitors (such resolution might not be satisfying or might not even exist), a workaround is to use the `--scale` option.
If you want `[monitor 1]` with resolution `[resx1]x[resy1]` and `[monitor 2]` with resolution `[resx2]x[resy2]`, you can use for instance

`` xrandr --output [monitor 1] --mode [resx1]x[resy1] --output [monitor 2] --same-as [monitor 1] --scale `echo "[resx1]/[resx2]" | bc -l`x`echo "[resy1]/[resy2]" | bc -l` ``

where the `` `echo "[res*1]/[res*2]" | bc -l` `` compute the desired ratios. Not guaranteeing perfect quality though; moreover, keep in mind that the quality of the resolutions set as above is limited by the resolution of `[monitor 1]`.

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me. Any idea how this corresponds to "Scale" (in %) on Ubuntu display settings?

Answer (score 4):

use the `xrandr --scale-from ...` option.

`xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale-from 1920x1080` will scale down the high resolution image of the external (HDMI1) monitor to the lower resolution LVDS1 laptop monitor.

Comment: A note to people with different aspect ratios (such as ultrawide 21:9 and laptop 16:9) is that this will make the laptop screen look compressed horizontally. I also noticed that switching in and out of the `--scale-from` mode make my screen go black or I can't click anything. The solution for me was to got into another tty (alt+ctrl+F2 for example and then back to the primary tty (F1). However, this did not always work and sometimes I was navigating my screen blindly, so it could be a good idea to try this out when you don't have anything important open and can afford a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the resolution is what the [xrandr source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c#n2022) does if you specify the `--same-as` relation:

```
case relation_same_as:
    output->x = relation->x;
    output->y = relation->y;
```

have you tried:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --output LSVD1 --mode 1600x900 --same-as HDMI1
```

?

Comment: You've misinterpreted that source quote.  The `x` and `y` relate to *position* not *resolution*.  Hence `--same-as` results in the monitor having the same top left corner position.  You certainly can set different resolutions and still use `--same-as`.