# Mirroring two displays with different native resolutions

Tags: display, xrandr

I have a 1920x1200 monitor connected using DVI and a FullHD television connected using HDMI. My video card is NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710]. I am running Linux Mint 21.

I would like to have a configuration in which the displays would be mirrored and I could change the resolution between 1920x1200 and 1920x1080. I would use the former for anything but Netflix (with TV off) and the like and the latter for them. Currently, the problem is that apparently the automatic discovery of supported resolutions is not listing 1920x1080 for the monitor and because of that, I don't have that available in configuration tools.

Currently, my work-around for this is to change not just the resolution but also the primary display. By making the TV the primary display, I can force the monitor to 1920x1080. I just have had this working more smoothly in the past when there was a xorg.conf that I could edit manually to add the missing mode line.

Just for the case it matters, inxi -G says

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] driver: nvidia v: 470.161.03
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia resolution:
    1: 1920x1200~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.161.03
```

I have found several web pages that instruct how to add custom resolutions, but they are not working for me.

Here is what I am getting with them:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 550mm x 343mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    59.81    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  

cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1080p"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 "1080p"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mirror dual monitors with different resolutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101490/mirror-dual-monitors-with-different-resolutions)

Comment: @Peregrino69 With help of that page, I managed to find this command that configures my system for Netflix and the like: "xrandr --fb 1920x1080 --output DVI-D-0 --scale-from 1920x1080". What is still missing is a command to undo what that does. It sets on a scaling that I can turn of only using the graphical Display tool. I'd like to find either a command to undo the scaling or a way to do this more smoothly using the graphical tool.

Comment: I usually make "undo" just by having 2 commands. The starting point is `X = Y`, my first command is `X = Z`; and the "undo" is obviously `X = Y`.

Comment: What I meant is that I didn't manage to find a command that would turn off the scaling. I had to use the graphical tool for that.

Comment: I may have found the undo command. It would be this: "xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --scale 1x1 --mode 1920x1200"

Comment: I would still like the possibility to make 1920x1080 appear in options for the display so that wouldn't need to set up scaling "manually", though.

Comment: Multi-monitor setups with different resolutions can be a headache, I've got my own probs with it :-)